# Gilbert - Varshamov bound

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

[The Gilbert - Varshamov bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Varshamov_bound) states for the binary case:
$$
{\frac  {2^{n}}{2^{k}}} \le \sum _{{j=0}}^{{d-1}}{\binom  {n-1}{j}}
$$

In the [Nielsen - Chuang textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=is%20the%20binary%20Shannon%20entropy,%20studied%20in%20detail%20in%20Chapter%2011&source=bl&ots=NG9Fbpow_r&sig=bZlozxbvtpfoLsQhW9jGqXyKQcM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPuYWly-DQAhVC5iYKHegECzMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=is%20the%20binary%20Shannon%20entropy%2C%20studied%20in%20detail%20in%20Chapter%2011&f=false) (p 449) it is given (for large $n$) as:
$$
\frac{k}{n}\geq{1-H(\frac{2t}{n})}
$$

In the above $H(x)$ is the binary Shannon entropy, $d$ is the distance of the code and $t$ are the bits in error. What are the steps to go from the first description to the second?

Comment: Isn't the inequality reversed?

Comment: @leonbloy the first is the formula under the section "An improvement in the prime power case" of the Wikipedia link for  q=2. Unless I am missing something very obvious , I think it is correct. The second is a direct copy from the Nielsen-Chuang text.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, for fixed $n$ the first gives $k \le \cdots$ and the second $k \ge \cdots$ ... Could you post a screenshot?  Perhaps we are assuming equality in the GV bound?

Comment: @leonbloy [this is the page from Nielsen - Chuang](https://books.google.com/books?id=-s4DEy7o-a0C&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=is+the+binary+Shannon+entropy,+studied+in+detail+in+Chapter+11&source=bl&ots=NG9Fbpow_r&sig=bZlozxbvtpfoLsQhW9jGqXyKQcM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPuYWly-DQAhVC5iYKHegECzMQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=is%20the%20binary%20Shannon%20entropy%2C%20studied%20in%20detail%20in%20Chapter%2011&f=false) eq. 10.63

Comment: Of course, the inequality is wrong. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)

$$ \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{n}{k} \le 2^{nH(m/n)} \tag{1}$$

Taking logarithms in the Gilbert - Varshamov bound, we get

$$n-k = \log_2\left({\sum _{{j=0}}^{{d-1}}{\binom  {n-1}{j}}}\right)\le n H\left(\frac{d-1}{n-1}\right)) = nH\left(\frac{2t}{n}\right)$$

where I've used $d = 2t+1$ and $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: How did you get to $\log_2\left({\sum _{{j=0}}^{{d-1}}{\binom  {n-1}{j}}}\right)=n-k$?